# Please help ID this plant

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees, fruit

Can anyone please identify this plant and confirm if the species is *Synsepalum dulcificum* (Miracle fruit)? Pics were taken near my house in Bangalore. Because the miracle fruit plant is not native to India, I'm guessing it is a different species.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like miracle fruit.

Comment: No, I don't think it's an S. dulcificum, the leaves are very different. It might belong to a related species.

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys!! really appreciate it! is there anyway to be completely certain of the species. I'll try eating a tiny bit of the fruit today just to see if it works. can anyone who has tried the fruit tell me how it tastes like and whether the effect is seen if a tiny amount is ingested.

Comment: Hmm could it be nightshade berries?